# Using Bootstrap Validator. How does it handle radio button validation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I am using [Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/). I am unclear on how to use it to validate selection of a radio button. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you need to use [HTML5's `required` attribute](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) on at least one of the radio buttons in the group. Bootstrap Validator's page has the following example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
            Boxers
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
            Briefs
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I removed the `required` attribute from one of the two radio buttons, it still wouldn't submit the form. When I removed both, the form submitted without me needing to specify a value for the radio button group.

After you've added the `required` attribute, make sure you have `data-toggle="validator"` specified on your form. Here's the full code:

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                Boxers
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                Briefs
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Alexander.